# how is it possible to create URLs according to model entries in django

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I have two fields **source** and **destination** in model cities

my application is named uroute.
if user inputs some details like: **source** >`paris`, **destination** > `bruxelles`

then url needs to be generated like this: `uroute/paristobruxelles`

i have tried like this:

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<source>+'to'+<destination>[A-Z][a-z]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

in views.py

```
def detail(request, source, destination):
    return HttpResponse(source+'to'+'destination')
```

i have no idea what to do with views.py
to be frank i am very naive to django.
i request somebody to guide through. thanks in advance!

Comment: What if the city name has `to` in it? (Eg Victoria, Launceston). Shouldn't it be better to do this like eg. `uroute/paris/brussels/`?

Comment: @Wtower there's no problem at all to do uroute/paris/brussels/ :)

Answer (score 4):

As Wtower pointed out in the comments, the approach you propose has a lot of edge cases you might encounter, like cities containing `to` in the name etc.

A more sustainable approach would be to maybe have something like `uroute/paris/to/berlin` if you wish to keep the `to` semantic of the URL.

Then it would allow you to easily capture the two cities in the following url pattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<source>[a-zA-Z]+)/to/(?P<destination>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]

def detail(request, source, destination):
    """
    Do something
    """
```